# How to add current time to a date in 24 hr format

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oop, datetime

I have a date coming from UI in "MMM DD, YYYY" format, my goal is to convert it in to proper dateTime format and add current time stamp(In 24 hr format) to it and save. I was successfully able to convert and add time to it but it's only taking the AM/PM format.

I tried Below

```
string dueDate = "Jul 9, 2017";
        string currentTime = date.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
        DateTime convertedDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dueDate).Add(TimeSpan.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")));
```

**Current:** 8/27/2017 2:05:00 PM

**Goal:** 8/27/2017 14:05:00

Is there a way I can get date in 24 hr format in DateTime Format (not in string).

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean. You cannot really add two dates together. Are you trying to take the current time and add it to the date that is provided and format the date as a 24 hours?

Comment: @John yes exactly, Im not trying to add two dates, I just want to add the current time to date in 24hr format and save it in db as DateTime type. Sorry for the ambiguity in my question

Comment: Grate will answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The date time object contains the date and time. It can then be optionally formatted in 24 or 12 hours.

You just need to build a new DateTime made up of the two parts:

```
string dueDate = "Jul 9, 2017";
DateTime input = Convert.ToDateTime(dueDate).Date;
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime output = new DateTime(input.Year, input.Month, input.Day, now.Hour, now.Minute, now.Second);
Console.WriteLine(output.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

Comment: The OP said that they do not want to use strings.  I wandered if he/she was referring to the Regional settings (in Control Panel) on the PC?

Comment: The last line is just to write out an example. You can push the output variable in to the database and the value will be correct.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean now.  +1 from me.

Comment: Or `var output = input.Add(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);`

Comment: @John Thanks a lot, this will still leave me with an output in AM/PM format..Is there a way that i can convert it to 24 hr hour format as DateTime variable (not as string)

Comment: The DateTime variable does not have a concept of AM/PM or 24 Hours it is just a date, time and timezone. In your UI you then choose how to format it. If you are looking at the database and it is showing as AM/PM then it may be a setting on how you are viewing it in the editor you are using. Can you explain more.

Comment: @John Sorry, im a newbie to C#, Lets say I have to store a dateTime value in DB...My question is...can I save in this format: "8/27/2017 16:05:00"? instead of "8/27/2017 04:05:00 PM"

Comment: If you are using a date time column in the database then  "8/27/2017 16:05:00" instead of "8/27/2017 04:05:00 PM" is just how it is shown to you on the screen not how it is stored but I think you have got that now. If you are storing the date time as a varchar in the db (bad idea) then that may be different. You can test  this by reloading form the db and reformatting in c# code.